# Change style in one Matplotlib Figure when working with several Figures simultaneously

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have 2 Matplotlib Figures at the same time that are updated in a for loop. One of the Figures (let's say `fig0` has images, while `fig1` is a line plot). I would like `fig0` to have the standard Matplotlib style while in `fig1` I would like to set `plt.style.use('ggplot')` for `fig1`.

So far I have tried this:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig0 = plt.figure(0)
fig1 = plt.figure(1)

for i in range(10):
    # print stuff in both figures
```

But this sets `ggplot` style in both Figures (as expected). I could not find the way to separately set style in each Figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would solve it, except for the loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with plt.style.context('ggplot'):
    plt.figure(0)
    plt.plot([3,2,1])
with plt.style.context('default'):
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot([1,2,3])

plt.show()
```

You'd probably be better off without the loop anyway... as long the loop isn't absolutely necessary for some reason. Just keep whatever you're adding to the plots in the loop in lists and modify the example above.